# alphabetically sorted imports

Tags: scala, import

I have

```
import scala.slick.jdbc.{GetResult, StaticQuery}
import scala.slick.jdbc.StaticQuery.interpolation
```

this can be shortened to

```
import scala.slick.jdbc.{GetResult, StaticQuery}
import StaticQuery.interpolation
```

but then it's no longer sorted alphabetically

This would be nice, but does not work, any alternatives?

```
import scala.slick.jdbc.{GetResult, StaticQuery, StaticQuery.interpolation}
```

Comment: You should avoid statements like "import StaticQuery.interpolation", as they usually lead to confusion.

Comment: Yeah it was not really great either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
import scala.slick.jdbc.{GetResult, StaticQuery}, StaticQuery.interpolation
```

But that leads to confusing block imports, which also increases the probability for merge errors when you work with other developers. Therefore you should always use absolute imports at the beginning of a file and use relative imports only inside of narrower scopes (like the body of defs).

Comment: I'll just go with the top one then